# How can I add margin to background bitmap on Android

Tags: android, xml, bitmap

So I would like to create a checkered effect with my bitmap. So I am using this very small pixel grey color png. I need to add a margin or padding before it's repeated but I'm unsure how to do this. Any help will be welcome as I have just started learning Android development.

What it's doing right now is repeating the entire image, filling the window with one color.

**Background.xml**

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bg"
    android:tilemode="repeat">

</bitmap>
```

**In my Activity Main XML I'm including the above XML**

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand You correct and You want to make an effect like this

[image]

Using a single grey pixel and adding margin to next before repeating, it will be much easier if You don't use:

[image]

But just a:

[image]

With a pattern like this, You can repeat an image and You will get a checkered effect.